# Unicode Character Circle Color

Tags: java, android, unicode, character

I'm developing an Android application and I'm using unicode characters.

I have a filled white circle with this code: '\u25cf'.

I want this circle in green and red (also filled). How can I achieve this?

When I change the color of the Textview all circles get the same color.

[image: Using unicode character in android application]

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the `TextField`'s color attribute. Assuming it is defined in XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/your_green"
    android:text="Hello"/>
```

Assuming you want it set programmatically:

```
int c = Color.parseColor("#ff0000");
mTextView.setTextColor(c);
```

or

```
int c = getResources().getColor(R.color.your_green);
mTextView.setTextColor(c);
```

Comment: thanks for this. But when I do it this way, all of my circles get the same color.

Comment: I see - take a look at Der Golem's solution. You will need to wrap each circle in `<font>` tags and manually specify each color there.